# Craft 3 - Plugin - Override Control Panel column values for field or field types

Tags: plugin-development, control-panel

How can I override the column value for a plugin in the Craft CMS control panel?

For example:

- Append "Hello " in front of a particular column value, or add hyperlink HTML markup to a value, in each row where the value makes a particular condition.

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to hijack column values!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how complex your needs, you might do with the following:

- [Control Panel JS](https://plugins.craftcms.com/cp-js)
- [Preparse Field](https://plugins.craftcms.com/preparse-field)

I've used this combo to alter field value display in the control panel.

For example, if a myField can contain a value of '1', then in a Preparse Field I do this:

```
{% if element.myField == 1%}ONE{% endif %}
```

And then using Control Panel JS, I can check the value of that field in the CP (in this case, checking for '1'), and then add/remove a CSS class, change the value of the HTML, etc. Part of the reason to use Preparse fields is they allow you to shorten the column header.

It's a little fiddly, but it works well.